# Weird soft body collision behavior

Tags: collision, soft-body

[image]I'm trying a simple collision between a soft body sphere, and a collision sphere that moves into it. The soft body sphere's vertex are jumping inside the collision sphere, before contact. Is it a simple setting I missed?

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Your information is not enough that we can help you. So as moonboots said, provide your blend file (so we can help you best) or screenshots from all relevant information we need like collision settings, soft body settings, scale…etc.